# Node-Red payload

Tags: node-red, payload

I'm working with a Mutitech MTCDT-H5-210A gateway.

I'm developing an application with the gateway that receives location data (longitude and latitude) via GPS / LoRa device.

I am using the Node-Red of the gateway itself to receive the device-LoRa data.

The gateway is already receiving data from device-LoRa.

However, the location data is sent by the device in Hexdecimal format.

I added one on base64 as picture 3

the payload result was "payload": "/f39Gf39/f0="

The correct output would be -23.62832, -46.69248 (latitude and longitude).
 
You could help me solve this problem, I'm new to this technology segment.

[image: image with no base64]

Comment: Are you sure it's ascii and not UTF-8?

Comment: Also what happens if you use the node-red-node-base64 node rather than a function node to decode the data

Comment: Edit the question, don't try and add code in comments

Comment: OK, so it's not utf-8. EDIT the question to include the original input to the function so we can see the base64 encoded input (as text NOT an image)

Comment: @hardillb I added one on base64 the payload result was "payload": "/f39Gf39/f0 ="

Comment: That base64 string does not contain what you think it does.

Comment: @hardillb I'm kind of lost, not sure what to do.

Would you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Without access to the system I can't really suggest where to start debugging the system. You need to verify the data at every step.

Comment: @hardillb Can you give me your email so I can send the teamviewer access data.

Comment: Only if you are prepared to pay my contract rate of £150 per hour